# Strange efficient frontier, when I try to calculate BTC & ETH ratios using MPT(Modern Portfolio Theory)

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, bitcoin

The 10k Monte-carlo simulations all fall on the same line, instead of a proper scatter plot..
Not sure what I'm doing incorrect. It all works fine, if I include Monero in the mix.
Any pointers ?

I'm doing some basic analysis (I'm a computer engg. but love finance). Read MPT & decided to find the "Max sharpe ratio" point.

Below is the graph.[image]
Also, here is the info. about the **max. sharpe point**:

stdev      0.668229
sharpe     1.516352
BTC-USD    0.630283
ETH-USD    0.369717

And below is how it looks for BTC, ETH & Monero. And yes, both take data from 01-01-2016 till now.

[image]

Comment: You need to share your code as well for us to understand your problem, no?

Comment: I found the issue, it occurs when I use two currencies. The plot distributes well when I use more than 2 assets.